# Why module.exports does not export a function properly?

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I'm building a project based on CJ's from Coding Garden [Inventory App](https://github.com/CodingGarden/inventory-app/tree/master/backend). In a knex migration file I have used an external file to bring a helper functions.

`tableUtils.js`

```
function addDefaultColumns(table) {
  table.timestamps(false, true)
  table.datetime('deleted_at')
}

function createNameTable(knex, tableName) {
  return knex.schema.createTable(tableName, table => {
    table.increments().notNullable()
    table.string('name').notNullable().unique()
    addDefaultColumns(table)
  })
}

module.exports = { 
  createNameTable, 
  addDefaultColumns 
}
```

and in my migration file:

```
const tableNames = require('../../src/constants/tableNames');
const { createNameTable, addDefaultColumns } = require('../../src/constants/tableNames');

exports.up = async (knex) => {
  await knex.schema.createTable(tableNames.user, table => {
    table.increments().notNullable()
    table.string('name').notNullable()
    table.string('email', 254).notNullable().unique()
    table.string('password', 127).notNullable()
    table.string('avatar_url', 2000)
    table.string('color', 15).defaultTo('#dddddd')
    table.specificType('balance', 'money').defaultTo('0')
    addDefaultColumns(table)
  })
};
```

Once tryint to run migration with `knex migrate:latest` I am getting error:

```
migration failed with error: addDefaultColumns is not a function
addDefaultColumns is not a function
TypeError: addDefaultColumns is not a function
```

What am I missing here as it looks like everything should work fine.. The function is declared with `function` and above `module.exports` so there shouldn't be a problem of function being undefined..

Comment: Your code shows you requiring `tableNames`, but you show a file named `tableUtils.js`.

Comment: omg that's so embarassing .. ; 'd thank you! too long a day in front of a screen

Comment: @RobertJamborski been there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code shows you requiring `tableNames`, but you show a file named `tableUtils.js` so it appears you aren't requiring the right file.